# Using glm to create a model matrix based off of three vec3

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

So I am trying to take three variables

```
glm::vec3 Translation;
glm::vec3 Rotation; //Euler angles
glm::vec3 Scale;
```

And make a model view matrix, that way each time one of those three vectors is changed I can pass a shader a new model view matrix.

My problem is that I only know how to tell glm how to translate/rotate at one parameter at a time.  And not only is that probably less processor efficent, but I suspect I would run into Gimbal lock with my euler angles.

I was wondering if you could help me make a function in glm that creates a model matrix ready to go to the shader.  This is sorta what I think it would look like. BTW i am in c++.

```
glm::vec3 Translation;
glm::vec3 Rotation; //Euler angles
glm::vec3 Scale;
glm::mat4 ModelMatrix
void UpdateModelMatrix()
{
    ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(); //set it to an identity matrix
    //Code stuffs


    //At this point the mat4 will reflect the scale rotation and translations above
}
```

I have tried using some quaternions math but it hasn't worked out.

Thanks much!

Comment: Why don't you create an X, a Y and a Z rotation and concatenate (multiply) them up.  Something like rX * rY * rZ * rS * rT.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using some quaternions math but it hasn't worked out.

Well, you probably should. But they are not always the best choice and if you want a simple, working solution, stick with matrices for now.

> is that probably less processor efficent

I don't think you should see a noticeable difference. Theoretically, `glm` uses some [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (`SSE`/`AVX`) intrinsics when possible. But on the other hand - I can tell you, that their code (especially for matrix transformations) is, well, average at most.

Now, you should be interested in these functions:

```
tmat4x4 rotate(tmat4x4 const & m, T angle, tvec3 const & v)
tmat4x4 scale(tmat4x4 const & m, tvec3 const & v)
tmat4x4 translate(tmat4x4 const & m, tvec3 const & v)
```

And use them this way:

```
void UpdateModelMatrix()
{
    ModelMatrix = glm::mat4();

    ModelMatrix = glm::translate(ModelMatrix, Translation);
    ModelMatrix = glm::scale(ModelMatrix, Scale);
    ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, rotAngle, Rotation);
}
```

You probably want to do things in this order - remember, that rotation is applied at the end (or at least after translation - otherwise object would be moved in different direction than intended).

Than, simply send your MM to your shader:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ModelMatrix));
```

Comment: **But on the other hand - I can tell you, that their code (especially for matrix transformations) is, well, average at most.** Could you enumerate what they could do better?

Comment: EIS support. The only one, that is utilized by `glm` is `SSE2`. In our software, where various matrix operations were really intensive, we got outstanding performance boost after implementing our own math library with support for all EISs from `SSE2` up to `AVX2`. Yes - it is supposed to be a general-purpose library, yes - our use case was quite specific and yes - maybe my 'average at most' was unfair and too critical. But statement from the doc saying, that `glm uses intrinsics and SIMD instructions whenever possible` is ridiculous for me.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - it is a *really* great piece of software and I have been using it for years. I simply found out, that it is not usable in some heavy scenarios - but not because of bad design or wrong implementation. Rather because of lack of something, that took me few days to implement.

Comment: I wrote my own matrix library myself, I'm not using `glm`. I was just wondering if there was something more than EIS support.

Comment: @Matesusz Grzejek thank you so much for explaining this.  I am still sorta stuck on rotation given a euler angles.  Won't we have problems if we rotate by one angle axis at a time?

Comment: I did find another tutorial on stack overflow that claimed if made a mat3 based off of a vec3 euler angle.  However I don't know how to apply that mat3 to my transformation matrix

Comment: `ModelMatrix = glm::mat4();`
If I used this statement it didn't update the Matrix with position. I removed this statement and it works. Besides, by default the glm::mat4 initializes an identity matrix. So the statement is redundant.